# Captcha is not working in rwd theme

Tags: magento-1.9, rwd-theme, captcha

I’ve installed magento edition version 1.9.2.0 and using rwd theme.I am combine the login form and create account form into one page
customer.xml is given

```
<customer_account_login translate="label">
        <label>Customer Account Login Form</label>
        <!-- Mage_Customer -->
        <remove name="right"/>
        <remove name="left"/>

        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="customer/form_login" name="customer_form_login" template="customer/form/login.phtml" />
            <block type="customer/form_register" name="customer_form_register" template="customer/form/register.phtml">
                <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="customer.form.register.fields.before" as="form_fields_before" translate="label">
                    <label>Form Fields Before</label>
                </block>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </customer_account_login>
```

Then Enabled the captcha feature under System>Configuration>Customer>Customer Configuration>CAPTCHA for Register form. captcha is working.but if we enter incorrect captcha it is not showing any error message like "Incorrect Captcha". I have copied captcha.xml to rwd theme and edit for displaying only for register form. the captcha.xml is also given

```
<customer_account_login>
        <!--<reference name="customer_form_login">
            <block type="core/text_list" name="form.additional.info">
                <block type="captcha/captcha" name="captcha">
                    <reference name="head">
                        <action method="addJs"><file>mage/captcha.js</file></action>
                    </reference>
                    <action method="setFormId"><formId>user_login</formId></action>
                    <action method="setImgWidth"><width>230</width></action>
                    <action method="setImgHeight"><width>50</width></action>
                </block>
            </block>
        </reference>-->
          <reference name="customer_form_register">
            <block type="core/text_list" name="form.additional.info">
                <block type="captcha/captcha" name="captcha">
                    <reference name="head">
                        <action method="addJs"><file>mage/captcha.js</file></action>
                    </reference>
                    <action method="setFormId"><formId>user_create</formId></action>
                    <action method="setImgWidth"><width>230</width></action>
                    <action method="setImgHeight"><width>50</width></action>
                </block>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </customer_account_login>
```

i don't know is this correct. but the captcha only shows for register form(that is my requirement) .plz help for correct working of captcha

Comment: I have the same magento version as yours ,when I followed [this toturial](http://www.atwix.com/magento/captcha-in-magento/ " ")
captcha worked fine for me.

Comment: For some inexplicable reason it was left out of the RWD design (someone else might be able to shed some light on this).
[http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/ce19-ee114/RWD_dev-guide.html][1]

  [1]: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/ce19-ee114/RWD_dev-guide.html

Comment: Easy solution https://magecomp.com/magento-new-recaptcha.html